# Is elevation and Truck routing API available for India

Tags: here-api

I tried with the below URL but didn't get elevation for the maneuver points in the legs segment. Is elevation API, and truck based routing, available in India?

[https://route.ls.hereapi.com](https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey=<API_KEY>&waypoint0=geo!27.9888,78.1351&waypoint1=geo!28.3954856,77.8605808&mode=fastest;car&returnelevation=true&routeAttributes=all)

Can I get truck based routing by selecting mode as - `mode=fastest;truck`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Truck based routing with elevation is available in India. You selection mode is correct to enable truck routing.

Elevation of a route can be enabled by setting parameter "returnElevation" to true.

*If set to true, all shapes inside routing response will consist of 3 values instead of 2. Third value will be elevation. If there are no elevation data available for given shape point, elevation will be interpolated from surrounding points. In case there is no elevation data available for any of the shape points, elevation will be 0.0. If jsonattributes=32, elevation cannot be returned.*

[Sample truck routing with elevation between Mumbai and New Delhi with HERE Routing API V7.2](https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?routeattributes=sh,gr&mode=shortest;truck&returnelevation=true&maneuverattributes=po,ti,pt,ac,di,fj,ix&language=en-us&jsonattributes=73&metricsystem=metric&waypoint0=geo!stopOver!18.94017,72.83483&waypoint1=geo!stopOver!28.63096,77.21722&app_code=%7Bapp_code%7D&app_id=%7Bapp_id%7D) - your own app_id/app_code needed

For details regarding truck routing and elevation, please check [the document page here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-calculate-route.html)

To get a feeling with different attributes and parameters available in the API, you can also try the  [reference client](https://refclient.ext.here.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I am using apikey based url for elevation extraction. https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json
?apiKey=<api_key>
&waypoint0=geo!18.94017,72.83483
&waypoint1=geo!28.63096,77.21722
&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled
&returnelevation=true. The url which you have shared needs app_id and app_code. Can you please help to understand why I am not getting elevation with api_key based url.

Comment: Please try add &routeattributes=sh to your API call, as the elevation values are part of returned shapes. Btw, the empty spaces in the call should be removed as well.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I added &routeattributes=sh. However in route>leg>maneuver>position, I am still getting only two elements - Latitude and Longitude. Elevation is not there.Is the url correct or still missing some element? I am using url - https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey=<api_key>&waypoint0=geo!18.94017,72.83483&waypoint1=geo!28.63096,77.21722&routeattributes=sh&returnelevation=true&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled

Comment: Actually, the elevations are returned as part of shapes, so route>shape instead of in position. {
"response": {
"route": [
{

"shape": [
"18.9401698,72.8348278,-53.0",

Comment: Thank you Team for the support, I got the elevation in shape. This one was through route API. Can I also fetch elevation by passing an array of lat-long values? Is there any separate API for fetching just elevation.